charmap and codec issues
I'm building an app with Python and TKinter. In the app i'm running Powershell commands. I'm having an issue with some results that i know that some of the characters are in Hebrew and i can't find a way to deal with the issue. it also might be some other special character which i don't know which.
Any help will be apprciated.
Here is the code that throwing an error:
import subprocess
username = input('Please enter user name: ')
command = f'Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity {username} | select name, GroupCategory, GroupScope'
result = subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', command], capture_output=True, text=True)
r = result.stdout

Here is the error:
Exception in thread Thread-1 (_readerthread):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1494, in _readerthread
    buffer.append(fh.read())
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1255.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 1263: character maps to <undefined>

I have tried google for it but all results talk about issues with opening files with special characters. I tried writing the results to a file but the same error.
I have tried assigning a variable Hebrew letters and print them and everything is fine.
So maybe it's some other special character which i have no idea which.

What is the output from PowerShell of [System.Text.Encoding]::Default? Please copy and paste the text output into the question using [edit]. No pictures.

I'm really confused how stack overflow system works, so spare with me.
I received a solution answer from @Mathias R. Jessen but i can't find it here in order to reply to it that his solution works. In fact there were other comments i don't see now.
Anyway thanks for everyone and specially Mathias R. Jessen.
The solution was to Replace text=True with encoding='cp862'
